# css viewport width: device-width doesn't work for some Android app's inner browser (say micro message)

Tags: android, css, viewport

I already set

```
@-ms-viewport { width: device-width; initial-scale: 1; }
@-o-viewport { width: device-width; initial-scale: 1; }
@viewport { width: device-width; initial-scale: 1; }
p { font-size:2em; font-weight:normal; white-space:normal; width:100%; color:#7b7b7b; }
```

in my css file, and i am sure it is loaded
The page is well displayed in Android default browser, but not in micro message inner browser.
The lines inside tag p is not 100% width in the preview display model. When I double click the screen to zoom in, lines inside tag p is just 100% width.

How to make the lines width auto adjust in the preview display model in all browser?

Thanks.